# PowerShell, unable rename registry on the remote computer

Tags: powershell

How can I rename Registry SubKey instead of deleting it on the **remote device**?

```
$remoteHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]“LocalMachine”;
$regKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($remoteHive,$computerName);

$profileList = $regKey.OpenSubKey(“SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\”,$true);
$remoteProfiles = $profileList.GetSubKeyNames()

ForEach ($remoteProfile in $remoteProfiles) {
    If ($remoteProfile -eq $strSID)
        {
            $profileList.DeleteSubKey($strSID)
        }
    }
```

I would like to replace `$profileList.DeleteSubKey($strSID)` with rename but can't find how.

Comment: [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-3-rename-a-registry-key) ?

Comment: @Theo not working 
Rename-item "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$strSID" -NewName "test"

Getting:  Rename-item : Cannot rename because item at 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-3020520201-138651245-3564099495-123456' does not exist.

Comment: You forgot the colon `:` directly behing ``HKLM:\``

Comment: thx @Theo but still not working. 

Weird thing is if I ``Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\"`` is true 

But  `Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-3020520201-138651245-3564099495-230881"` is false

Comment: after wrapping in `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -scriptblock`  Test-Path worked but still not able to rename.

Comment: If I do with var is not working 

`$strSID = "S-1-5-21"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -scriptblock { 
Rename-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$strSID" -newname "S-1-5-21_BAK" -Force
} -ErrorAction Stop`

But is I do without, it is woking  `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -scriptblock { 
Rename-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21" -newname "S-1-5-21_BAK" -Force
} -ErrorAction Stop`

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, so I'll post it as answer instead.
The reason why

```
$strSID = "S-1-5-21"  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Scriptblock { 
    Rename-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$strSID" -NewName "S-1-5-21_BAK" -Force
} -ErrorAction Stop
```

doesn't work is because inside the scriptblock, variable `$strSID` is unknown.
You need to either scope it in the scriptblock with `$using:strSID`, or send it as parameter to the scriptblock like:

```
$strSID = "S-1-5-21"  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Scriptblock { 
    param([string]$SID)
    Rename-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$SID" -NewName "$($SID)_BAK" -Force
} -ArgumentList $strSID -ErrorAction Stop
```

Renaming registry keys could be dangerous of course and you should be aware of the [Well-known SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers#well-known-sids), making sure you don't try to rename these too..